# How do I start "Ubuntu classic desktop" (no effects) from the command line

Tags: gnome, command-line, ssh

I am able to run sessions over an ssh connection but I rather use the "Ubuntu classic desktop (no effects)" version on Ubuntu 11.04 instead of the new Unity since I don't have 3d support on the laptop I'm using to display the graphical User Interface.  How can I startup the older gnome-session without the 3d effects?  I tried gnome-session but it seems to be the option with the 3d effects and I want a more stripped down session over my ssh session.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Invoke GNOME applications over ssh from another machine?

Comment: I'm trying to invoke a full Gnome session so that I can use the Gnome menus and notifications on screen to invoke different applications.  I want it to be the same as when I login to my desktop using the "Ubuntu classic desktop (no effects) without needing to be sitting at my desktop.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the command line the GNOME Classic Desktop is started with:

```
gnome-session --session=gnome-classic
```

Other session types are installed by default in `/usr/share/gnome-session/sessions/` and can also be opened with the `gnome-session --session=SESSION` command where SESSION is the name of the `SESSION.session` file stored.

Comment: The correct path seems to be '/usr/share/gnome-session/sessions/' and I see the following in the directory: 2d-gnome.session  classic-gnome.session  gnome.session  ubuntu.session

Comment: Note that the version 11.10 doesn't have the classic-gnome by default so you have to use 'ubuntu-2d' instead.

Comment: Note I found this to readd the classic gnome desktop: http://www.liberiangeek.net/2011/08/return-to-ubuntu-classic-desktop-in-ubuntu-11-10/

Comment: I tried those, and none of them worked

Comment: @anonnymouse: we can only call sessions that are predefined in our system. The answer was valid in 2011 but today we need to install the **gnome-session-flashback** package and then may be able to call this session with `gnome-session --session=gnome-flashback-metacity` (can't  try atm, if it works I'll edit my answer later)

Comment: I set `gnome-session --session=gnome` to run `gnome` instead of `gnome-classic` but `gnome-classic` is still launched.